# Oracle 'sysman' account

Tags: oracle

In Oracle, is `sysman` is the most powerful user or are there other equally privileged users?

Answer (score 2):

Any user with SYSDBA privilege is your "most powerful" user. They are on equal footing. The owner of the data dictionary, SYS, is the "classic" superuser in Oracle.

BTW, SYSMAN is not a SYSDBA user by default:

```
C:\>sqlplus sysman@db as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Tue Apr 27 10:27:15 2010

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges


Enter user-name:
```

If you are able to use OS authentication, it overrides password authentication:

```
C:\>sqlplus /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production on Tue Apr 27 10:30:04 2010

Copyright (c) 1982, 2007, Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.

SQL> conn sysman as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> select user from dual;

USER
------------------------------
SYS

SQL>
```

Comment: SYSMAN is the owmer of the enterprise manager repository

Comment: And it's not a SYSDBA user by default.

Answer (score 0):

SYSMAN is mainly a user used for monitoring purposes

if you have an OEM (grid) instance, it will usually use this user by default to monitor your database instances, so his rights are limited, like DCookie said.

SYSTEM and SYS are the most powerful users (SYS being the highest)